# how to test if the time is daylight saving or not using command line?

Tags: python, command-line, timezone

I can manually check whether it is daylight saving or not. But is there a way to check this using command line or a program (e.g., python)?

Comment: With a 600+ rep, you should know that this question is too broad to be on topic; https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Python, From:** *[Python daylight savings time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881025/python-daylight-savings-time)*

```
import time  
print(time.localtime().tm_isdst)
```

> Returns 0 or 1 Depending on Daylight Saving

**For CMD You could try:**

```
tzutil /g
```

or

`Powershell -Command "(Get-Date).IsDaylightSavingTime()"`