# Calculate sun position ephem module DST dependent

Tags: python

I have this piece of code to calculate the position of the sun but its not DST dependent. I have to change on each DST switch between sunset_time - 5 to sunset_time - 4
Can be done this using some module of time zone?
Thank you.

```
class sunClass():
        def __init__(self):

                self.home = ephem.Observer()
                self.home.lat = '45.xxxxx'
                self.home.long = '-73.xxxxx'
                self.home.elevation = 35
                self.home.pressure = 0
                self.home.horizon = '-3' #'-6'  # civil twilight = -6 deg
                                                # nautical = -12
                                                # astronomical = -18
                self.sun = ephem.Sun(self.home)

        def getStat(self):
                return self.home.previous_rising(self.sun) > self.home.previous_setting(self.sun) # get sun position

        def getSunset(self):
                sunset_time = self.home.next_setting(self.sun)
                sunset_local_time = ephem.Date(sunset_time - 5 * ephem.hour) #local time
                return sunset_local_time

        def getSunrise(self):
                sunrise_time = self.home.previous_rising(self.sun)
                sunrise_local_time = ephem.Date(sunset_time - 5 * ephem.hour) #local time
                return sunrise_local_time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't comment, so I put this here, even if it's really a comment...

Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881025/python-daylight-savings-time) help you?

Comment: Thank you, I miss this link somehow.